# Unbounded Knapsack with multiple bins and constraints

Tags: knapsack-problem, or-tools, operations-research

I'm new to Python coding and need help to solve an unbounded knapsack problem with multiple bins (4 bins) and constraints.

1. The bins have weight constraints of 10.5, 10.5, 7, and 7 respectively.
2. Each bin can be filled with certain items only. For example, bin 0 can be filled only with items 0-9, bin 1 is can be filled only with items 10-19, and so forth.
3. The algorithm runs recursively until the total weight constraint of 3000 is reached.

I've modified the code available from or-tools as follows. The output is very close to what I require, but I'm having trouble with items 2 and 3.

```py
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp


def main():
    data = {}
    data['weights'] = [
        0.95,0.31,0.95,0.95,0.95,0.95,0.95,0.95,0.95,0.75,0.95,0.78,0.45,1.00,1.00,1.00,0.19,1.00,1.00,0.50,3.00,3.00,3.00,0.75,
     1.25,5.00,3.00,1.00,3.00,1.00,1.00,0.63,3.00,1.00,0.55,1.00,1.00,0.75,0.67,0.38
    ]
    data['values'] = [
        0.8554,0.7855,0.7406,0.7282,0.7855,0.8653,0.8529,0.9177,0.8329,0.9077,0.7706,0.8928,0.8354,0.9077,0.8379,0.8055,0.8778,
     0.8778,0.9252,0.9501,0.9451,0.9377,0.9252,0.9102,0.9252,0.9476,0.9426,0.9476,0.9377,0.9302,0.9401,0.8579,0.8678,0.8903,
     0.8853,0.8105,0.9077,0.9152,0.9152,0.8579
    ]
    assert len(data['weights']) == len(data['values'])
    data['num_items'] = len(data['weights'])
    data['all_items'] = range(data['num_items'])

    data['bin_capacities'] = [10.5, 10.5, 7, 7]
    data['num_bins'] = len(data['bin_capacities'])
    data['all_bins'] = range(data['num_bins'])

    # Create the mip solver with the SCIP backend.
    solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver('SCIP')
    if solver is None:
        print('SCIP solver unavailable.')
        return

    # Variables.
    # x[i, b] = 1 if item i is packed in bin b.
    x = {}
    for i in data['all_items']:
        for b in data['all_bins']:
            x[i, b] = solver.BoolVar(f'x_{i}_{b}')

    # Constraints.
    # Each item is assigned to at most one bin.
    for i in data['all_items']:
        solver.Add(sum(x[i, b] for b in data['all_bins']) <= 1)

    # The amount packed in each bin cannot exceed its capacity.
    for b in data['all_bins']:
        solver.Add(
            sum(x[i, b] * data['weights'][i]
                for i in data['all_items']) <= data['bin_capacities'][b])

    # Objective.
    # Maximize total value of packed items.
    objective = solver.Objective()
    for i in data['all_items']:
        for b in data['all_bins']:
            objective.SetCoefficient(x[i, b], data['values'][i])
    objective.SetMaximization()

    status = solver.Solve()

    if status == pywraplp.Solver.OPTIMAL:
        print(f'Total packed value: {objective.Value()}')
        total_weight = 0
        for b in data['all_bins']:
            print(f'Bin {b}')
            bin_weight = 0
            bin_value = 0
            for i in data['all_items']:
                if x[i, b].solution_value() > 0:
                    print(
                        f"Item {i} weight: {data['weights'][i]} value: {data['values'][i]}"
                    )
                    bin_weight += data['weights'][i]
                    bin_value += data['values'][i]
            print(f'Packed bin weight: {bin_weight}')
            print(f'Packed bin value: {bin_value}\n')
            total_weight += bin_weight
        print(f'Total packed weight: {total_weight}')
    else:
        print('The problem does not have an optimal solution.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Point 2 should be easy enough: simply constrain `x[i, b] == 0` for all i not from 0 to 9 for b=0, for i not in 10 to 19 for b=2, etc. Or better, don't even create those variables, they will always be false and not contribute to the weight in the bin. On your third point, I'm not sure I understand what you mean with "total weight constraint of 3000". The 4 bins can only hold a sum total of 35, right?

Comment: Thanks, Christopher. It turns out that recursion isn't necessary. You've sufficiently answered my question.

Comment: another question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70448674/multiple-knapsack-with-constraint-on-binding-items-to-bins-with-or-tools has some aspects similar to this one. Maybe you can answer it with some of your working code.